# Allow Non-Admins Permission to Manage Windows Firewall

Tags: permissions, powershell, windows-firewall, non-admin

I am attempting to setup a process for our support team (non-administrators) to have access to remotely enable or disable a group of Windows firewall rules.

I did the following to get to the point of allowing remote access...

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force

winrm quickconfig

Set-Item -Path WSMan:\Localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value '$supteam' -Concatenate

New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName <dispName> -Profile <profile> -Enabled True -Action Allow -RemoteAddress $supteam -Direction Inbound -LocalPort <winRMport> -Protocol TCP -Program System
```

When running the command...

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <ipAddress> -ScriptBlock { netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="<ruleGroupName>" new enable=<yes/no> } -Credential $creds
```

I get the following output...

> The requested operation requires elevation (Run as administrator).

The PowerShell session from which I am running the above command is open as Administrator (i.e. the title bar reads "Administrator: Windows PowerShell").  User Account Control (UAC) is turned off on the destination server.

NOTE: I have also tried using the PowerShell equivalent for (en|dis)abling the firewall rules...

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <ipAddress> -ScriptBlock { Get-NetFirewallRule -Group "<ruleGroupName>" | <Enable/Disable>-NetFirewallRule } -Credential $creds
```

And get the following output times 3 (one for each rule)...

> Access is denied.
>
> + CategoryInfo: PermissionDenied: (MSFT_NetFirewal...ystemName =
>   ""):root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetFirewallRule) [Enable-NetFirewallRule],
>   CimException
>
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 5,Enable-NetFirewallRule
>
> + PSComputerName        : ipAddress

I can get a list of the rules using...

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <ipAddress> -ScriptBlock { Get-NetFirewallRule -Group "<ruleGroupName>" } -Credential $creds
```

So I am taking it that (en|dis)abling firewall rules can only be done by members of the local Administrator group of the remote server.

If my assumption is correct, is it possible to allow a non-admin group access to modify the firewall?  If so, any instructions or links would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows security boundary, not a PowerShell issue. So, not a simple PowerShell script this. It's an environment and policy configuration.

You need to grant the needed permissions to the use or account that your control to make these settings.

The other option is to leverage PowerShell JEA (Just enough administration) and constrained endpoints.

[Using JEA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/jea/using-jea)

```
$nonAdminCred = Get-Credential
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName localhost -ConfigurationName JEAMaintenance -Credential $nonAdminCred
```

[Just Enough Administration (JEA) Infrastructure: An Introduction](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Just-Enough-Administration-6b5ad370)

> Just Enough Administration (JEA) provides a RBAC platform through
>   Windows PowerShell. It allows specific users to perform specific
>   administrative tasks on servers without giving them administrator
>   rights. This allows you to fill in the gaps between your existing RBAC
>   solutions

[JEA Helper Tool 2.0](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/JEA-Helper-Tool-20-6f9c49dd)

> This script provide a graphical "helper" to several Just Enough
>   Administration (JEA) features, for Windows Management Frameworek (WMF)
>   5.0 and Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 4 (TP4)

[PowerShell: Implementing Just-Enough-Administration (JEA), Step-by-Step](https://sid-500.com/2018/02/11/powershell-implementing-just-enough-administration-jea-step-by-step/)

Leverage PowerShell Just Enough Administration for your Helpdesk

> With JEA, you empowers your users to perform specific tasks through
>   PowerShell without providing them elevated rights. You can control the
>   available commands and parameters, validate input for the specified
>   parameters, and have full auditing capabilities with over-the-shoulder
>   transcripts, module logging, and deep script block logging.

[Introduction to PowerShell Endpoints](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/31/introduction-to-powershell-endpoints/)